# Usable memory less than actual memory?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I'm having a problema similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/236136/installed-memory-4gb-but-only-1-93-gb-is-usable-shows-in-system-properties-dialo). I've updated the BIOS (UEFI, actually), tried to change things in msconfig and now I'm trying to make the memory remapping, but there is no such option on my UEFI (my motherboard is a 990FX Extreme 4) and yet, it seems that the system is locking 4GB of RAM (Windows 7 64):

> [image]

- Is there some place where I could change the ammount that is being locked?
- Is there some place in which the memory remapping feature is *hidden*?

**EDIT:** I've just installed a brand new copy of Windows 10. It became worse: It's now locking 6GB:

> [image]

I really think that there is some kind of hidden configuration in Windows in which I could change that.

Comment: It is possible you could discover more by running the (usual) memtest86 from a flash stick, not being in a windows OS. Verifying there in the test, that is 8gig shown, that the 8 gig all tests at least once, in only the first testing (would not take long). Then you know the bios isn't the likely problem, and you know that the module slot placement, and connection stuff is not any aspect of the problem (when it can be raced through once).  In windows you could go to the device manager, and "vew resources" by type, and attempt to see things there.

Comment: Please list all your system specs, not just the board, in the case that someone spots something obvious, like some CPU with limitations, or a ram compatability issue or anything else.  Please also edit the Tag or the question to show that it is Windows 7 64bit, and any other information, like even the bios version etc.

Comment: look to the BIOS/UEFI if there is a memory remapping option and toggle it.

Comment: @Psycogeek I did it. But iut showed the memories are okay.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I wrote in the text that there is no memory remapping. Unless it's cloaked with a utterly different name.

Comment: You need to post more information for us to help you.  Is this your motherboard:  http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/990FX%20Extreme4/?cat=Specifications     Is your RAM installed properly?  ftp://europe.asrock.com/Manual/990FX%20Extreme4.pdf   Is your RAM listed on the Motherboard compatablity list?