# Bios and System showing different RAM size

Tags: windows-8, memory, 64-bit

I just installed **DDR2 2 GB** Ram into my PC where i have already installed 1 GB Ram. **I check bios it showing correct total 3GB RAM but system properties showing only 2 GB.** I also check using Z-CPU id 3rd party software it is also showing 3 GB. What is the problem why computer property not showing correct amount of RAM i also didnt mention any size of ram in ms config settings.

My pc configuration(quite old) are:

Processor : intel celeron 346, 3.06GHz

Board: Dell, chipset Model :0TY915

windows 8, 64 bit

Note: *I reinstall win8 64 bit but it didn't work. What is the problem? why only bios and 3rd party software showing orignial installed memory and system itself not?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installed memory 4GB but only 1.93 GB is usable shows in system properties dialog?](http://superuser.com/questions/236136/installed-memory-4gb-but-only-1-93-gb-is-usable-shows-in-system-properties-dialo)

Comment: load default BIOS settings